# Checking currently displayed Fragment with Espresso (No virtual method getFragments())

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso, android-testing

I try to unit test my application for changing fragments behaviour. (Menu navigation)

I have tried with this code to get the **currently displayed fragment:**

```
 public static Fragment getVisibleFragment(Activity activity) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
                return fragment;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This little helper function and my tests **ran verry well** on Xiaomi Mi A1 (Android 8)

But I **got error** on SAMSUNG Galaxy S8 (Android 7)

The error is the following:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getFragments()Ljava/util/List; in class Landroid/app/FragmentManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.app.FragmentManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
at device.helper.TestHelper.getVisibleFragment(TestHelper.java:32)
at device.ui.UITestUserSettings.changingTabs(UITestUserSettings.java:302)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:433)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:375)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1962)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#getFragments()) was only added in API 26 so that is why it can't be found on S8.
I haven't found any other API method to get the actual fragments. You could create a Collection to store fragment ids/tags and update it every time a change occurs.